# AJAX only works on page refresh

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

I am writing a web app that allows a user to create questions and assign answers and point values to those answers.  I have it set up so the user enters how many questions they want to make and then I pull up all the fields needed for one question.  When the user clicks Save & Next button those fields are cleared and they can enter their next question information.  I am using `AJAX` to post the model data to my server each time Save & Next is clicked.  My problem is that my `AJAX` will only run if I allow the page to refresh which I don't want to do.

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" id="next" value="Save & Next" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#next').click(function(e) {

        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        e.preventDefault();

        if (counter <= ques)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Questions/Create",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.serialize(model),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data)
                {

                }
            });
            //counter++;
        }
        else {

        }

    });
});
```

**C# Server-Side**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public int Create(QAViewModel qa)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("madeit");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in qa.questions)
            {
                //add question data into the DB
                db.questions.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (var item in qa.questionAnswers)
            {
                db.answers.Add(item);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return(1);
        }

        return (0);
    }
```

The real problem comes with `e.preventDefault();` If I remove it the code runs and my model data gets added to my database as expected.  When `e.preventDefault()` is added the AJAX code after it is not even executed. I have tried used `<input type="button">` since it's default action does not do anything.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**SOLUTION**
After many hours the solution was to use `@Html.AddAntiForgeryToken()` on my view.  I forgot that I was checking for anti forgery token which did not let the AJAX to post data to my controller action.

Comment: Can't understand what you're asking ' When e.preventDefault() is added the AJAX code after it is not even called'

Comment: @ZeeTee I am trying to prevent to page from reloading while still adding the data to my database.  However if i use e.preventDefault() the ajax code which follows immediately after does not run.  Not sure if that clears it up for you or not

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but did you try moving the `e.preventDefault()` call after the ajax call?

Comment: sounds like a problem with your conditional `if`. WHere are `counter` and `ques` defined? I bet they throw erros which is why code isn't firing

Comment: @Bic i agree that it shouldnt matter, and yes I have tried moving it

Comment: @charlietfl they are defined else where but it's not that because again I can run it with that if statement without the e.preventDefault()

Comment: @charlietfl may be on the right track. If the ques and/or counter variables are updated elsewhere, the `e.preventDefault()` execution could stop the page from getting to the code which would perform those updates.

Comment: @urnotsam you are only assuming that, without preventDefult() the form will submit using browser default. Check for console errors.

Comment: @charlietfl for the time being i do not even need to check that condition so I removed it and it will still not work.

Comment: But what **exactly** isn't working? Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: what is JSON.serialize?  That looks like your problem. You need to use browser console to check for errors as well as implement ajax erro handler

Comment: @charlietfl heres a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b51bhfjn/8/ if you test this it will show you the alert.  If you comment out `e.preventDefault()` it no longer does.  I dont know why that code wouldnt run with e.preventDefault

Comment: You really need to look at console errors. Demo throws one right away because of imporper code

Comment: @charlietfl where did the demo throw you an error because it didnt for me

Comment: You're clearly still not looking at the console. You can open it by pressing F12. The demo you linked errors out because you don't define `e` in your click event. Therefore `e.preventDefault()` throws and undefined, as `e` does not exist. It is very likely that something similar is happening in your actual app code. You really should look at the console.

Comment: @Bic your right my firebug script setting was off

Answer (score 2):

You are using a non existent function `JSON.serialize`. If you want to convert a javascript object or array to JSON string use `JSON.stringify(object)`

This issue can easily be found by using your browser console to check for errors thrown

Comment: Your right I was using a .NET function in my javascript.  I wish i could say this fixed the problem though.  +1 for continuing to help me with problems

Comment: well you need to use console to see what's not working. Inspect actual request. You also will save considerable amount of time implementing ajax error handling

Comment: I know, thanks.  It has something to do with e. It is not defined so i will be looking into that

Answer (score 1):

Submit buttons are made to *submit* content of the form.

When you don't need to submit, you should use a normal button. However, if for any reason you still want to use a submit button, you may want to `return false` at the end of the method, in order to avoid submit button to do its work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

        if (counter <= ques)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Questions/Create",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.serialize(model),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data)
                {

                }
            });
            //counter++;
        } else {

        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1dqyuvcx/)

Comment: event.preventDefault() will accomplish what you are trying to do with `return false`. In case like this it's actually more reliable if code after it has errors . If errors thrown there will be no return

Comment: same results as when i try preventDefault()

Comment: @charlieftl: you are right but in this case there's no error catch, so both `preventDefault()` and `return false` give the same result because the interpreter stops somewhere.

Comment: @DavideRossi actually not quite right. Since `JSON.serialize` is undefined, it will throw error blocking remainder of code and form will submit default. At least with `preventDefault` at beginning of code, you can see the error since page won't refresh. I used `return false for years myself, mostly because it was faster to type but there is a small downside to it

Answer (score 0):

A quick and kinda dirty fix is to hold a boolean to use whether u do the prevent default or not.

```
var preventBoolean = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#next').click(function(e) {

    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    if(preventBoolean)
    {        
         e.preventDefault();
    }
    preventBoolean = true;

    if (counter <= ques)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Questions/Create",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.serialize(model),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                 preventBoolean = false;
            }
        });
        //counter++;
    }
    else {

    }

});
});
```

I'm not sure where u want to turn it on again but I have set it in the succes.
The good solution is binding and unbinding the method but then you have to work with events.

Comment: huh? That will cause form to submit using browser default

Comment: ooh yah didn't noticed that. is it possible that you change it to button instead of submit button? <input>